# Как вызвать класс из функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста решить такую задачу. В классе А в функции Afun2_1 нужно вызвать класс B из функции Afun1

```
class A:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.B_cls = B()
        self.C_cls = C()
        
    def Afun1(self, a, b, c):
        class B:
            def __init_(self, a, b, d):
                self.a = a
                self.b = b
                self.d = d
            def Bfun1(self):
                """something colculation"""
                return """solution 'Bfun1'"""
        
        class C:
            def __init__(self, f, g, h):
                self.f = f
                self.g = g
                self.h = h
                
        def Afun1_1(self):
            """something colculation"""
                
    def Afun2(self, a, e):
        def Afun2_1(a, l):
            """something colculation"""
            **"""And here for colculation, I need to get 'class B'. How to do it ? """**
            return """solution 'Afun2_1'"""
```

Comment: А действительно, зачем вам классы внутри методов класса?? По-нормальному даже функции внутри функций не нужны особо (кроме декораторов), так и классы внутри чего-то другого тоже непонятно зачем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном контексте не очень понятно, с какой целью классы лежат внутри методов.
Когда класс лежит внутри метода, то его объявление ограничено областью видимости этого метода. Однако, это не
мешает использовать его вне метода. Например, можно присвоить объявленные внутри метода класса полям класса контейнера, как в примере ниже, и затем обращаться к соответствующим полям через экземпляр класса контейнера:

```
class A:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.B,  self.C = self.Afun1(1,2,3)
        
    def Afun1(self, a, b, c):
        class B:
            def __init__(self, a=a, b=b, d=c):
                self.a = a
                self.b = b
                self.d = d
            def Bfun1(self):
                """something colculation"""
                return f"called Bfun1: B.b is {self.b}'"
        
        class C:
            pass

        return B, C
                
    def Afun2(self, a, e):
        def Afun2_1(a, l):
            return self.B(a, l).Bfun1()
        return Afun2_1(a, e)

a = A()
rv= a.Afun2(111,2222)
print (rv)



## output:

# called Bfun1: B.b is 2222'
```

Answer (score 0):

В классе `А` в функции `Afun2_1` вызвал класс `B` из функции `Afun1`:

```
class B:
    def Bfun1(self):
        return """solution 'Bfun1'"""


class A:
    def Afun1(self):
        b = B()
        print(b.Bfun1())

    def Afun2_1(self):
        self.Afun1()

a = A()
a.Afun2_1()
```

Результат:

```
solution 'Bfun1'
```